# Why use multer rather than manually upload your files from controller

Tags: node.js, express, multer

So im new on using expressjs, usually i choose Laravel as my backend. but because some certain consideration, i choose expressjs.

On Laravel, when we handling file upload, we can write upload logic everywhere, its your freedom to do that. You can encapsulate it inside your model function, or put it on service, or anywhere you want.

But when i use expressjs, so many articles on internet that recommend us to use multer for upload your file. As my background is using Laravel previously, i found its weird to use multer. Its because multer is a middleware. Why on earth we use middleware to upload our images/files.

With this i cant encapsulate my  business logic into one service and its make the code separated and with this thats mean i need to maintain one business logic from multiple place.
Could you explain me why everyone choose multer ?

why dont just upload it to our local storage manually ?( actually for now i dont know how to do this ). 
What is pros on mins from using this library ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, [Express/body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) does not handle file uploads natively, so that is why you see other libraries being loaded to handle them.  They are all going to be loaded as middleware so they can be injected into the request and handle that a file was actually uploaded.

Coming from a Symfony background, I understand where you are coming from with wanting to handle things more manually, as I do the same. There are other alternatives to multer; for example I use [express-fileupload](https://github.com/richardgirges/express-fileupload) which allows you to load the the uploading middleware for your entire app, and then you can use `req.files` to handle your uploads.  For example:

```
// load the file upload library as app middleware
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');

app.use(fileUpload({
  limits: { fileSize: 50 * 1024 * 1024 },
}));
```

Then let's say you have a file input named 'foo':

```
<input name="foo" type="file" />
```

In your route you would handle it like so:

```
// now handle a file upload
app.post('/upload', function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.files.foo); // the uploaded file object
});
```

The file-upload documentation has examples for the `req.files` object as well as options you can pass to the middleware itself.

Comment: Ah i see, thank you, its make my undestanding about multer much clearer, but sorry out of topic, i just curious, so that's mean when i use laravel, they parse All of the request for me eh? And is laravel do file upload same as multer? Are they will store uploaded image on our server fist so that we can access it from $req->files()? If its so,then thats mean UploadedFile object is pointing file from our local storage eh?

Comment: Laravel will parse multipart/form-data files for you; it would be difficult to say whether it uploads the 'same' as multer, as I'm not sure what you mean. Their documentation has more information here https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/filesystem#file-uploads ; the library I mentioned about, express-fileupload, defaults to storing files in RAM but allows for storing to disk instead.

Answer (score 2):

`multer` is a *body parsing middleware* that handles content type `multipart/form-data`

That means it parses the raw http request data which are primarily used for file upload, and makes it more accessible (storing on disk / in memory /...) for further processing.

Without multer, you would have to parse the raw data yourself if you want to access the file.

> With this i cant encapsulate my business logic into one service and
>   its make the code separated and with this thats mean i need to
>   maintain one business logic from multiple place. Could you explain me
>   why everyone choose multer ?

`multer`, just like other middlewares, can be used at the root for all routes, but can also be put on only specific routes too.

More on express [middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html#middleware.application)

Comment: Hm. Yeah but for using multer, it will store our uploaded image from multipart/form-data to the defined storage path first. I found its weird. How can we limit the upload if file already uploaded. And is it mean that we need to delete this uploaded image manually if the business logic that has an upload feature fails?

Comment: You configure file size limits with multer. Aside from disk storage engine, multer also has memory storage engine, where you can access the file as `Buffer` and the file will not be stored to disk. multer also supports custom storage engines where you can handle the storage by yourself or with plugins like  s3 or gcs.

Comment: oh i see, so thats mean if i use local storage then thats meani need to delete my previously uploaded file from multer after business logic finish. 
Ok thank you very much sir. its help me a lot. Thanks!